# Detect IE browser and open the same url using chrome browser

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am using WordPress to build a project. After adding a nice theme template, it looks nice using google chrome browser, however when using IE browser, some of the feature does not shown up. So I was wondering is there some methods that could detect if user using IE browser and it could automatic open chrome and browse the same URL(saying all our user install chrome already), and close IE.

Or is there any other approach to this problem?

Comment: No, you cannot do that. Fix the IE CSS/script issues.

Comment: That's impossible. What you can do is have a cross-browser compatible CSS. Mostly based on a shim and polyfills. That would be a lot of work, so you would really revert to Bootstrap. For a WordPress theme that means it requires you to fix it by hand or avoid it.

Comment: I make a bat file upload on the server and make a link in IE page if doesnt show properly. bat simply do: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "the url i want to redirect" --new-window

Answer (score 1):

You can't and shouldn't do this.

JavaScript should not have access to the user's system, and also this is a terrible UI feature if it could be implemented.

A better way to handle this is:

1. Detect IE and show some sort of alert that suggests they use a different browser
2. Make your website compatible with IE to the extent that you feel comfortable

Comment: I make a bat file upload on the server and make a link in IE page if doesnt show properly. bat simply do: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "the url i want to redirect" --new-window

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do, if you gone to far into the project is to use different stylesheet for IE:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <link href="IE-styles.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Or, if there is a problem with specific version of IE use:
(Targeting IE8, and older)

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Hope this helps.